# Lazyload image listen scroll event only vertically issue

Tags: ionic3, lazy-loading

I am using a ng-lazyload-image, link is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-lazyload-image1

When I integrate it with my code, anything fine except I discover when the list is only scroll horizontally, it can’t lazy load the image, only when you scroll vertically, the image will loaded, anybody know how to solve it.

My code is:

```
<img [defaultImage]="'assets/img/productDefault.png'" [lazyLoad]="product.imageUrl" [scrollObservable]="container.ionScroll">
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@fmendoza has a mostly workable solution for horizontal scroll inside Ionic2+ and `ng-lazyload-image` (https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image/issues/158) - bind through `[scrollTarget]="scroll1._scrollContent.nativeElement"`:

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" direction="x" #scroll1>
    <div class="item" margin *ngFor="let item of newItems" (click)="goToItemPage(item)">
        <img src="./assets/imgs/placeholder.png"
            [lazyLoad]="item.photoThumb?.url()" 
            [scrollTarget]="scroll1._scrollContent.nativeElement"
        />
        <div text-center text-wrap>
            <p no-margin>{{ (item.shortName || item.name) | excerpt:17 }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```